# How to change iframe source pieces with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, src

So I am trying to make a function that can replace the src of the iframe. In the iframe there would be a map with two places. In the html code there are two forms for the place ID-s.

I just cannot get this to work.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div id="start">
    <label for="startLocation">Start location ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="startLocation" name="startLocation" value="" ><br><br>
</div>

<div id="dest">
    <label for="destination">Destination ID:</label>
    <input type="text" id="destination" name="destination" ><br><br>
</div>

<button onclick="changeMap()">Show the map!</button><br><br>

</form>


<iframe id="map" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" src="" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

This would be the function:

```
function changeMap(){

//place IDs to put into url
var start = document.getElementById('startLocation').value;

var dest = document.getElementById('destination').value;


//pieces of the url
var mapSource1 = "https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?origin=place_id:";

var mapSource2 = "&destination=place_id:";

var mapSource3 = "&key=AIzaSyDMtNzjQdNk-FX1hz7IWVcNiby1B8xiZeg";

var mapSource = mapSource1+start+mapSource2+dest+mapSource3;

//iframe
var iframe = document.getElementById('map');

//changing the src of the iframe
iframe.src = mapSource;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
<button onclick="changeMap()">Show the map!</button><br><br>
```

may be causing the problem.

To begin with, `button` elements, if not given a `type="button"`, are considered `submit` buttons. So every time the button is pressed, the form gets submitted and the browser starts loading a different page before the JavaScript has time to do much.

Secondly, I see you are using `onclick` to attach the event handler. If your script has to be *above* the `form` in your HTML, this will result in `changeMap` being undefined. I would suggest attaching the event handler with JavaScript, something like this:

```
<button type="button" id="show-map">Show the map!</button><br><br>
```

```js
var btn = document.getElementById('show-map');
btn.addEventListener('click', changeMap);
```

Note that because the this is selecting the `button` element right here, either the `script` tag must be placed *below* the `button` (so the button is around--can't select nothing!) or the JavaScript needs to be placed in a `document.onReady` function, so that the script won't fire until the page finishes loading (which means the `button` will be fully loaded).

Unless you're using `document.onReady`, the order of the `script` tag and `button` really matter. If the `script` references the `button`, the `button` comes first. If the `button` references the `script`, the `script` must come first.

Wrapping in some sort of `document.onReady` is common practice. jQuery has a function ([`$.ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)) that can be used to do this, but if you're brave [you can also do it without jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#ready).

Also, keep in mind `addEventListener` doesn't work on older IE. You could [polyfill it](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#on) or use jQuery.

Comment: wow, thanks! actually I've just started with javascript and html, so I had no idea about these things..:) You wrote that the script shouldn't be below the form, but if the javascript is in an external file, how can that even happen? Or is it better to place the script in the HTML? Thankyou!

Comment: @Ilka Pardon my earlier, self-contradictory comment. I just deleted it. Yes, if you use `onclick` to set event handlers, your `script` tag _must come first_. It doesn't matter if it's just referencing an external file or not. Simply move the tag _above_ the `button`.

Note that `onclick` isn't really recommended, even though you can do it. It is considered Good Practice to use `document.onReady` and `addEventListener`.

PS: Keep in mind `onclick` and `document.onReady` cannot be used together.